# Qt Set Background Color of QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, background, qlineedit, palette

I'm trying to change the background color of the `QLineEdit` and I can't figure it out at all.

I tried using `stylesheets` originally like this

```
QLineEdit *le = new QLineEdit();
le->setStyleSheet("background:#000;");
```

but that didn't do anything. I tried using `QPalette` like this

```
QPalette palette;
palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::black);
palette.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::black);
le.setPalette(palette);
```

but this didn't do anything either. I've been looking all day and can't find anything. am I doing something wrong or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
QLineEdit *le = new QLineEdit();
le->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(0, 255, 255); selection-background-color: rgb(233, 99, 0); }");
```

Answer (score 21):

You can set the background and text colors of line edit by setting the palette like :

```
QLineEdit *le = new QLineEdit();

QPalette palette;
palette.setColor(QPalette::Base,Qt::black);
palette.setColor(QPalette::Text,Qt::white);
le->setPalette(palette);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code is almost correct. Only QLine edit uses the Base color. So if you do not want to replace existing stylesheet which can contain borders padding and margin and you want to change background only, use QPalette:

```
QPalette palette = _ui->lnSearch->palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::green);
_ui->lnSearch->setPalette(palette);
```

Thanks to: https://forum.qt.io/topic/64568/why-setting-background-color-of-qlineedit-has-no-effect

Answer (score 4):

I had to use background-color from standard css like this:

```
QLineEdit* edit = new QLineEdit();
edit->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {background-color: black;}");
```

I am using Qt 5.4