# Why can't I use StyleSheet in QLineEdit object?

Tags: qt

I have a class `DragQLineEdit` which inherits the `QLineEdit`.

I have defined an array as:

```
DragQLineEdit m_textEdits[FAVORITE_ROWS][FAVORITE_COLUMNS];
```

So I am able to generate a grid of edit text boxes. FINE.

But when I want to change the color say of the very first edit text box like this:

```
m_textEdits[0][0].setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(255,255,255); selection-background-color:rgb(233,0,0); }");
```

It gives me compiler error: **no member named StyleSheet**.

I did the above after reading the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283435/qt-set-background-color-of-qlineedit) question.

Basically, I have the following function:

```
void Favorites::mySlot(int r,int c,int row,int col)
{
    m_sendButtons[r][c].setText(m_sendButtons[row][col].text());
    m_sendButtons[row][col].setText("Send");

    m_textEdits[r][c].setStyleSheet(m_textEdits[row][col].StyleSheet);
    m_textEdits[row][col].setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(255,255,255); selection-background-color:rgb(233,0,0); }");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have...

```
m_textEdits[r][c].setStyleSheet(m_textEdits[row][col].StyleSheet);
```

It should be...

```
m_textEdits[r][c].setStyleSheet(m_textEdits[row][col].styleSheet());
```

Note the lower case 's' in `styleSheet` and parentheses after `styleSheet` signifying a function call.